# Failed to start custom template in openvz

Tags: linux, templates, centos, openvz

I have created custom template in openvz webpanel. I can use this template to create  VM's,
but i can't start them.

Here is the output after executing `vzctl start 333` 
Starting container...
The ploop library has been loaded successfully
[ 0.000673] Opening delta /vz/private/333/root.hdd/root.hdd
[ 0.013293] Adding delta dev=/dev/ploop14100 img=/vz/private/333/root.hdd/root.hdd (rw)
[ 0.031071] Running: fsck.ext4 -p /dev/ploop14100p1 
/dev/ploop14100p1: clean, 18/144288 files, 262254/576256 blocks
[ 0.066517] Mounting /dev/ploop14100p1 at /vz/root/333 fstype=ext4 data='balloon_ino=12,' 
Container is mounted
Setting iptables mask 0x1c000007
Setting features mask 0000000000000001/0000000000000001
Container start failed (try to check kernel messages, e.g. "dmesg | tail")
Killing container ...
Container was stopped
[ 1.577279] Unmounting file system at /vz/root/333
[ 1.609521] Unmounting device /dev/ploop14100
Container is unmounted

Here is the `dmesg` output

[1787074.182270]  ploop14100: p1
[1787074.192013]  ploop14100: p1
[1787074.209486] EXT4-fs (ploop14100p1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
[1787074.210530] EXT4-fs (ploop14100p1): loaded balloon from 12 (6144 blocks)
[1787074.212305] CT: 333: started
[1787074.318074] CT: 333: stopped

here is the output of `tail -n 10 vzctl.log`

2014-10-01T08:08:07+0000 vzctl : CT 333 : Setting iptables mask 0x1c000007 
2014-10-01T08:08:07+0000 vzctl : CT 333 : Setting features mask 0000000000000001/0000000000000001
2014-10-01T12:08:07+0400 vzctl : CT 333 : Container start failed (try to check kernel messages, e.g. "dmesg | tail")
2014-10-01T12:08:07+0400 vzctl : CT 333 : Killing container ...
2014-10-01T12:08:08+0400 vzctl : CT 333 : Locked by: pid 773361, cmdline vzctl start 333
2014-10-01T12:08:08+0400 vzctl : CT 333 : Container already locked
2014-10-01T12:08:09+0400 vzctl : CT 333 : Container was stopped
2014-10-01T12:08:09+0400 : Unmounting file system at /vz/root/333
2014-10-01T12:08:09+0400 : Unmounting device /dev/ploop14100
2014-10-01T12:08:09+0400 vzctl : CT 333 : Container is unmounted

I have noticed that when im starting container `top` catches 2 processes that start it same time.
Its only problem with custom templates and i have tried to make a template via terminal but it doesn't start too.

Comment: mount the container and examine it's log files, ie: vzctl mount 333; less /vz/root/333/var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

I can see there are some issues with the Iptables modules on your server. Can you please disable the iptables in chkconfig and try to boot your server again .